# The counting of special character differs from normal character in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this problem about character counting

When I input five five = 11 characters
But five/five = it counts more than 11 characters i don't know the exact number but I'm pretty sure that it exceeds 11 characters

Anybody can help me ? It will be highly appreciated. Thank You

This is my code

```
function get_pop_post_excerpt($limit){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 40);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
return $excerpt;
}
```

this is actually a Wordpress site

Comment: can we see the code? and example input and output?

Comment: So `$fivefive1 = 'five five';
$fivefive2 = 'five/five';

var_dump(strlen($fivefive1), strlen($fivefive2));` gives `int(9)
int(9)`. But it could be a problem with `utf-8` charset. One string is in `utf-8` the other not.

Comment: please edit your question. Put your code there

Comment: there is 9 character including white space

Answer (score 0):

Try count the chars with [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-strlen.php). It could be that one string is `utf-8` encoded and the other not. You're 11 chars for effective 9 chars also indicates that's an encoding problem.